# Muddy coloured outline when drawing PIL rectangles?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to draw a rectangle in Pillow that has no Fill, just a white outline rectangle to frame an object.

However, I've noticed that when I set `width=1` then I don't actually get the colour that I set, instead I get this muddy looking grey.

To investigate I've turned the width up to 7 and I get a nice thick white box, exactly what I'm looking for albeit far too thick. But the rectangle has that muddy coloured outline on it.

I tried setting outline to None but it doesn't work. I'd be happy if instead of the outline it showed my white line on width=1. Am I missing a setting?

Also as an aside, is there any way to get `width < 1`? I noticed it takes an integer value but I'd love an even finer line.

My current code:-

```
import PIL.Image as img
import PIL.ImageDraw as imdrw

idraw=imdrw.Draw(im)
idraw.rectangle([r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3]], fill=None, outline=None, width=1)
```

I initially tried that last line as

`idraw.rectangle([r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3]], fill=None, outline="#ffffff", width=1)`

EDIT: To explain this a bit clearer... It's like there's a border around my outline. And when I set the outline width to be low enough (e.g. = 1) then it ONLY shows the border, which is a muddy grey colour. If there's a way for me to either get rid of this border, OR change the border colour to white then that works too.

Comment: The 1 in `with` is one pixel, so I don't think it's less than that.

Comment: @r-beginners it possibly just looks worse for me because of this border that's around my outline then. Because it really doesn't look like 1 pixel

Comment: You seem to have omitted to post your image, and include your MCVE *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"*.